# how can I output the websocket live feed to client browser DOM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dom, websocket

These are my goals.

1. connect to websocket API as a client
2. output these websocket messages to a specified browser DOM(client-side)

.

1. connecting to websocket on nodeJS

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const url = 'wss://websocket.example';
const ws = new WebSocket(url);

ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    wsMessages = JSON.parse(event.data);
    wsMessagesTime = wsMessages.t;
    wsMessagesData = wsMessages.d;
    console.log(wsMessagesTime, wsMessagesData);
};
```

from here I can console.log the `wsMessagesTime` and `wsMessagesData` during every event and I can see the live feed from my nodemon.

Now I would like to output that to my browser dom element.

2. output these websocket messages to a specified browser DOM(client-side)

```
const {log, error } = console;
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const server = app.listen(3000, log('server is running on 3000'));

app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    console.log('root page logged')
})
```

from here, I put my `index.html` file inside the `./public` directory.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>websocket testing</title>
    <script> var exports = {};</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>hi this is a test string</h2>
    <div id="websocket data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

From here, I want to render my websocket data feeds onto the div element with the id `websocket data`.

From my research express is server side so I dont have access to the DOM
even view engines like ejs doesn't let me put data into the specified DOM. (correct me if I'm wrong please)

I simply want to render the output from `console.log(wsMessagesTime, wsMessagesData);` to the local webpage running on the express server into the div element specified as `websocket data`.

Comment: Use browser's network tab.

Comment: @omidh Any other suggestions? I need to be able to render the websocket messages onto a dom element on the webpage. Not just see the websocket messages through the console or the network tab.